# Import error using pdftotext - symbol not found in flat namespace

Tags: python, macos, homebrew, pdftotext, poppler

I have an issue running a python script. I'm running the latest version of MacOS with python 2.7.

I've tried downgrading my modules, python version, and pip version which hasn't done anything. I tried uninstalling pdftotext and updating it. I have poppler installed via homebrew on the latest version. Nothing I'm doing is working and I think I'm looking in the wrong direction.

```
  File "run.py", line 4, in <module>
    import controllers
  File ".../controllers.py", line 33, in <module>
    import common.parser as parser
  File ".../parser.py", line 36, in <module>
    from common.parse.coned import get_building_coned_data, get_coned_reports_list
  File ".../coned.py", line 17, in <module>
    from common.coned.bill_scraper import RE_TOTAL_CHARGES_TYPE
  File ".../scraper.py", line 6, in <module>
    import pdftotext
ImportError: dlopen(.../env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pdftotext.so, 0x0002): symbol not found in flat namespace (__ZN7poppler24set_debug_error_functionEPFvRKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEENS0_9allocatorIcEEEEPvES9_)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to install poppler-utils. poppler-utils are precompiled command-line utilities (based on Poppler) for manipulating PDF files and converting them to other formats. poppler-utils is available for Python 3.x only, so you will need to update your Python script to be compatible with Python 3.x.

To install poppler-utils run the following commands:

```
brew install poppler
brew install --cask pdftotext
python3 -m pip install poppler-utils
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the project the rest of the project is in python 2.7 so I can't use python3 here. Is there any other utility I can use that is compatible with 2.7? Thanks for responding by the way!

Comment: Maybe you can find an old version of poppler-utils for python 2.7.

Comment: Thank you Karel for your answer which enabled me to install pdftotext on my mac. Oddly the second command `brew install --cask pdftotext` doesn't find pdftotext, instead I get `Error: Cask 'pdftotext' is unavailable: No Cask with this name exists.`

Comment: @JulianHarty With macOS Big Sur and later, running `brew install...` without cask will work.